# Using jQuery .get to show parameters in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When using a GET request on a form in regular HTML we get the variables within the URL. Is there a Jquery way to sent variables like this by clicking a button? I have been looking into Jquery .get but i can't get my parameters to show up in the URL.

Following does not load the page and add to URL, it just runs the code with specified parameters.

```
$.get( "home.php", { name: "menyo" } );
```

So i am looking for a way to do this in a clean Jquery way. It is because i have many buttons that do various Jquery things and i do not want to create a form for each one with their own get request while i automated buttons with button classes using custom attributes in the HTML.

Comment: When doing ajax, the parameters aren't added to the URL in the browser, another request is made asynchronously in the background instead, which is sorta the whole point of ajax ?

Comment: The only way to do this is to use the [history api](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Comment: I think you misunderstand the concept of AJAX. What is your goal? Why do you want the GET parameters to end up in your address bar?

Comment: So i am stuck with adding 24 html forms for my buttons just for the GET requests? Like i said i have these buttons that do Jquery magic on there own in a couple of lines but i cannot do a simple GET request within the click function?

Comment: Where do you want these GET parameters? In your actual address bar?

Comment: @putvande Well, i want people to bookmark or link to specific content. But indeed i rather not want the complete page to reload.

Comment: Do you want to stay on the same page while changing the URL in the address bar or do you want to actually go to another page?

Comment: @putvande Well, i want to load content within my page with Ajax but being able to retrieve that data from a single link. I don't care how ;)

Comment: And you want people to be able to bookmark it.. for that last one you probably need HTML5 History Api as already mentioned earlier in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to create a method that will find all inputs in given form and prepare a JSON Object with key value pair.

something like that

```
function getFormJson(formId) {
    var jsonObject = {};
    $("form#" + formId).find("input").each(function (i, item) {
        jsonObject[item.attr("name")] = item.val();
    });
    return jsonObject
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To move the location of the window I believe you can do something like this:

```
window.location.href = "home.php?name=menyo";
```

Otherwise I'd look into checking out pushState, which will change the URL of a page without actually taking you there.

pushState docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState().C2.A0method

Otherwise, you can use classic AJAX

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "where/you/need/the/variables.php",
        data: { 
            "name" : "menyo"
        },
        success: function(data){
            // data is the returned output of the page
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: that would cause a page change which OP doesnt want

Comment: changing location.href changes the page, didn't mean the history api pushState method

Comment: Assumed since he was using an ajax method that he wasnt wanting to change the page. otherwise why use js at all just do a normal form